# Missing </meta> for Google and Twilio

Tags: google-calendar-api, twilio

I am trying to receive calls using Twilio and below is the error I am receiving in my Twilio console

> 12100 Document parse failure
>
> > Error on line 1253 of document  : The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
> >
> > > 12100 Document parse failure
> > >
> > > > Error on line 1253 of document  : The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

After reviewing the error, most of the codes in it is not mine and it came from google, none of the codes is from me. Anyone here knows how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the TwiML response that you are generating  ?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?517353-How-to-put-meta-tags-to-blogger), try to fix it by removing the `</meta>` and replacing it with `<meta... />`. You can check this [documentation](http://ezpctips.blogspot.com/2009/05/adding-meta-tags-seo-part-ii.html) on how to add meta tags properly.

This related ticket might also help:

- [The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</META>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526248/the-element-type-meta-must-be-terminated-by-the-matching-end-tag-meta)

> I can think of two explanations for what is happening:
>
> - Sometimes the document is being generated or created incorrectly.
> - Sometimes you are getting an HTML error page instead of the document you are expecting, and the XML parser can't cope with a
>     `<meta>` tag in the HTML's `<head>`.  That is because the `<meta>` tag
>     in (valid) HTML does not need to have a matching / closing `</meta>`
>     tag.  (And for at least some versions of HTML, it is not allowed to
>     have a closing tag.)
>
> To track this down, you are going to have to capture the precise input
>   that is causing the parse to fail.